# "Pending" status for orders paid via Auth.Net

Tags: php, magento, authorize.net

In my Magento store, I have the following payment methods enabled with these order statuses:

- Zero Subtotal Checkout - Pending
- Check / Money Order - Pending
- Authorize.net (Auth only) - Processing

The problem is that it makes it difficult for the admin to determine which orders have been invoiced/paid and which have been shipped.

Ideally I would like new orders to always have a "Pending" status.  When the invoice is created (which will trigger the Capture for Auth.net orders), it should go to "Processing".

**It appears that I cannot set the "New Order Status" for Auth.Net to "Pending" - any idea why this is, and/or a workaround/solution for it?**  I suppose a possible solution could be adding new columns to the order table such as "Invoiced" and "Shipped" so that the admins can easily see/filter by those statuses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **New Order Status** can only be one of the status of *Processing* state because it's defined that way in **app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/etc/system.xml**:

```
<order_status translate="label">
    ...
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_processing</source_model>
    ...
</order_status>
```

If you want to change that behaviour, you can simply override this configuration setting. In your module, create a system.xml file (in **app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/system.xml**) and in it put:

```
<config>
   <sections>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <authorizenet translate="label" module="paygate">
                    <fields>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New Order Status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_new</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                    </fields>
                </authorizenet>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

you will then be able to select "Pending" as the new orders status.
If you prefer the new columns in the orders grid solution, just ask and I'll answer.
HTH